# Meaning of: Delivered, Received, Tap to chat

Tags: snapchat

Snapchat shows a kind of status under each contact's name in the chat list:

[image]

In the screenshot above it is "Tap to chat", but sometimes it is "Delivered" or "Received".

**Question**: What are all possible statuses, and what is the meaning of each?

Comment: [Seen this?](https://snapchat-download.net/what-does-delivered-sent-and-opened-mean-on-snapchat/). I don't use Snapchat so can't confirm but it's in line with WhatsApp

Comment: @beeshyams: That external webpage is outdated, the terms have changed.